# MapTo Either silent fail when it's not matched

Tags: scala, akka, future, spray

I have the following code that silently fail without catching any error:

```
(actor ? GetRowCount()).mapTo[Either[Rejection, Long]] map {
      case Left(x) => ctx.reject(x)
      case Right(totalRows) => ctx.complete(totalRows)
}
```

When `GetRowCount()` does not return a `Long`, but a `String` for instance, no error was caught and it just silently fail.

I am thinking to use the following:

```
(actor ? GetRowCount()).mapTo[Either[Rejection, Any]] map {
      case Left(x) => ctx.reject(x)
      case Right(totalRows: Long) => ctx.complete(totalRows)
      case _ => ctx.reject(Rejection("Type mismatch"))
}
```

But is there a better answer?

Answer (score 0):

I would use `recover` or `recoverWith`

```scala
(actor ? GetRowCount).mapTo[Either[Rejection, Long]] map {
  case Left(x) => ctx.reject(x)
  case Right(totalRows) => ctx.complete(totalRows)
} recover {
  case e: Throwable =>
    logger.error(e, "Some thing wrong while performing ask")
    //throw an error or return something here
}
```